# Using AWS Glue behind a VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-glue

So we are starting to explore AWS Glue service as an ETL service. The largest outstanding question in our org. is "How will we be able to develop these scripts without console access?" Enter development endpoints. I fully understand how we can use the repl/zeppelin notebooks to develop our scripts and test them in our development VPC on AWS.

My only question is, does AWS allow you to keep those development endpoints inside of a private subnet? It seems that the endpoint has a public DNS. We have a policy of not allowing an instance to have a public DNS endpoint. Are we screwed here? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!